# I am trying to write the logs of a specific camelContext into a seperated Logfile

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-camel

I am trying to write the logs of a specific camelContext into a seperatetd Logfile.

When I use 
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel = INFO, Loggername
log4j.additivity.org.apache.camel= true

It logs every log from camel

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about how you run Camel, eg do you use an app server. And what version of log4j do you use etc.

Comment: Hi, of course. I am using it on a tomcat. And I use log4j 1.2.17 with slf4j-log4j12

Comment: I run camel to organize my file import and export and processing. Controlled by activiti workflows , each of them have their own camelContext.

Comment: I am not sure how it works in Tomcat but in Karaf you could use MDC logging to get each camelcontext to log in separate files. You need to enable MDC logging in Camel.

Comment: Oh, thank you i didnt't think of that :|

Comment: Do you mean your application logs or Camel framework logs?

Comment: I mean the camel framework logs. The question can be closed i simply wrote an appender an  link it in the camelcontext with                              <bean id="LogegrName" class="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
      <constructor-arg value="com.logger" />
</bean>